# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.Java heap space error in Processing 2

Tags: java, macos, memory, processing, heap-memory

Help!

I'm getting this error in my processing sketch:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.Java heap space

My sketch runs a lot of .png image sequences simultaneously, using depth data from the kinect. I think I just need to increase my max heap space memory available in Java or Java Virtual Machine, but I can't figure out how to do that. The information I can find requires a level of understanding of java that's beyond my skill level. Would anyone be willing to post a walk-though for mac or a link to one? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This looks like your first question on this site. Please take a look at the site FAQ section to know more about how to post a question or take a look at some of the highly rated questions. There are many posts scattered across stackoverflow that already answer your question. For instance, go to google.com and search the term `stackoverflow java increase memory`.

Comment: @Cking, thank you for adding this comment. Downvotes without feedback do very little to help someone get better at research and asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command line option.

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
```

[More information here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#nonstandard)

If you are running you program from command line use,

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx4096m <main class>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. where do I add this though? In terminal? In my processing sketch?

Answer (score 0):

Maximum and starting memory allocated by the JVM can be parametrized by vmargs

-Xmx : maximum memory that will be allocated

-Xms: starting memory

example: with vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx2g your jvm will start with 512Mb of allocated memory and increase it to a maximum of 2Gb